# Quadratics and tangents

Tags: geometry

I've got this question I'm working on and I've got the correct answer but the worked solution in the back of the book doesn't make much sense and I'd like someone to help me understand.
The question states, given the function $y =4x^2 + 1$ find the tangent $L$ such that it goes through the point $(0,-8$). The way I did it was realising the line is in the form $y=mx -8$ then substituting this into the quadratic and finding the discriminant and setting it equal to $0$. However my textbook does a really weird method and there is one bit that makes no sense. I've attached the textbook solution and I'd like someone[image] to explain it, thanks
More specifically how it's allowed to write the equation of a straight line as $y=8x^2-8$ which is obviously a quadratic.

Comment: How is it possible that this very **old** use of the word "line" for ... a curve be still used in 2022 ? It is by no means a straight line...

Comment: The tangent is straight line. How it is we have write the tangent as a quadratic.

Comment: What is the book you are working on ? It is complete nonsense !!!

Comment: The slope of the curve is $8x$. Since the line has the form $y=mx+b$ which your author calls $y=mx+c$ we get $y=8x^2+c$ for the line. Notice in the end he ends up with $m=8\cdot\frac{3}{2}=12$.

Comment: Yes I get that. However I don't get the bit where they multiply the $8x$ and $x$ together because that makes a quadratic?

Comment: It still represents a line. The slope changes with $x$ so the family of potential lines is quadratic in $x$. Notice that once he solves for $x$ he only plugs it into the $8x$ to get the slope that corresponds to the line that solves the problem.

Comment: Ok. But the issue is this. If we say the tangent to the curve is of the form $y=8x^2+c$ this is wrong as if we sub in $x=1$ we get $y=8+c$ which is obviously wrong as it has gradient 0 and not gradient 8.

Comment: But he doesn't do that. This solution is perfectly valid. We can't just look at an expression and say it's wrong; we have to look at the arguments surrounding the symbols.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how he doesn't say that $y=8x^2+c$ is a tangent?

Comment: He doesn't plug a value in for x and conclude that $y$ is a constant. He is representing the line as $y=m(x)x+c$. It's a clever way to solve the problem. How would you have preferred he solve it?

Comment: Since he uses the gradient what he calls "line" are the called in Spanish "curvas de nivel" (I don't know how call these in English, (perhaps "level curves"?). Give distinct values to $c$ and you will see some kind of parallelism with the curves you get. This way the intersection with $y=4x^2+1$ gives the tangent. (it is more "elegant" than making discriminant equal to zero).